How to extract one specific table from many Firebird 2.5 database backups?
I have a bunch of backups of the same Firebird 2.5 database. I restored them using this batch:
rem @echo off
C:
cd "C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin"
gbak -c -user SYSDBA -password masterkey "C:\1.fbk" "C:\1.fdb"
gbak -c -user SYSDBA -password masterkey "C:\2.fbk" "C:\2.fdb"
etc...

Now I have 1.fdb, 2.fdb and so on...
Ist it possible to extract one specific table (let's say called ZW) from all these DBs in one flow and save it as CSV file? I could use FlameRobin and extract one by one, but it would take ages.

It can be faster if you write a shell/batch script. And even faster with new Firebird versions where gbak allows to restore only chosen table(s).

What would such a shell/batch script look like?

Something like this for Windows: for %fn in c:\*.fbk do gbak -c -rep %fn tmp.fdb && fbexport -D tmp.fdb -F %fb.cvs -V zw.

There is nothing in Firebird itself that provides such functionality, and I don't know of any tools that do. To be honest, it sounds like a bit of an odd and specific requirement. If you need something like that, you'll probably need to write a program that does this yourself.
